# Is there a scalar version of a variable label?

Tags: stata

Is there a way to get a scalar version of a variable's label? From `return list` or `ereturn list`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach your objective by first using a macro extended function to create a local macro containing the variable label, and then assigning the value of the local macro to a scalar.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. local make_lbl : variable label make

. display "`make_lbl'"
Make and Model

. scalar sc = "`make_lbl'"

. display sc
Make and Model

.
```

Comment: You can also telescope the two into one. Putting into a `local` is entirely optional.